# Power consumption of text, voice, and video packet over a wireless network?

Tags: power, wireless

Does the power per packet vary for different data types such as text, voice and video? 
If so, does it mean that since text uses lesser number of bytes, it also requires less power to transmit?

Comment: Sorry, but can anyone one of you kindly specify as to why the question is "too broad". The question in itself is of generic nature (wireless networks). So, one gets the point that the question is about the `consumption of the power per packet` for the `various data types` (3 to be specific) over `any wireless networks`. Yes, answers have been pouring in but each of them does provide certain valid points. So, please point out the mistake in my question and at least justify the action for putting it on hold, only then it would seem fair.

Comment: SMS text messages are occasionally sent directly over a control channel instead of a data channel, depending on the cell protocol. In this case, it is conceivable that text messages would require less energy to transmit as the message can be sent directly in the control channel as opposed to having to request a data channel to send the information.

Answer (score 2):

For a radio receiver, the generally accepted formula that governs how much signal receive power is needed is based on data rate: -

Power needed = -154 dBm + 10log\$_{10}\$(data rate)

If the power needed is less for lower data rates then the transmitter can lower its transmit power however, there is another thing to consider. At lower data rates the power may be reduced but the transmission takes much longer hence the total amount of transmit **energy** used remains about the same.

Comparing speech against data, the power per bit for digitized speech can be acceptably lower because of the inbuilt ability of humans to "decode" crappy distorted speech and still understand it. I've read that maybe up to ten times lower energy per bit is acceptable ([Essentials of Radio Wave Propagation by Christopher Haslett](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjYwJKS2czMAhXrKMAKHW9QBLgQFggrMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.ksu.edu.sa%2Fzhejaz%2FEE%2520423%2FBook_Cambridge_Essentials%2520of%2520Radio%2520W%2520Propag_ED_2008.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGOeNdlnkJU2haq9SdEJ3eKWa8xJg&sig2=reWprVTPE6fQWPAbZnRbfQ&cad=rja) pages 15 and 16 provide the main details).

Comment: What does `-154 dBm` signify? Attenuation?

Comment: Basically, if a radio receiver is perfectly designed to accept an incoming data rate of 1 bit per second, the power needed from the antenna is -154 dBm. If it is designed to receive 1 Mbps then the power needed from the antenna is 60 dB higher at -94 dBm. This is at ambient normal temperatures i.e. higher temperatures = higher background noise and this means more power needed at the antenna to overcome thermal noise.

Answer (score 1):

The power per packet solely depends on the number of bytes in the packet, and the efficiency of the transmitter. It does not depend on what the transmitted bytes represent. So, whether the packets hold text, voice, or video is not relevant. Moreover, video, for example, could be transmitted as a file over FTP, or as streamed data, in which case the protocol overhead and packet size is completely different. So it is *really really* not relevant.

Comment: So, if the video is streamed, what effect would it have? more power consumption than FTP?

Comment: Honestly, I can't answer that. It depends on the details of the protocols chosen. Usually, streaming uses UDP, and file transfer uses TCP. TCP has a larger overhead. On the other hand, streaming cannot always use the biggest packet size because data has to be split regularily to be sent as a constant rate, so it is less efficient. All in all, you'd have to study every detail to answer this, but it's for sure different.

Answer (score 0):

Data is a set of ones and zeros, the only difference is in how they are arranged. The issue has more to do with the volume of data as opposed to its content. Assuming that the transmitter is *just a transmitter*, power draw should not be dependent on data. However, the volume of data in a txt is far less than in a video stream so the txt uses the same *power* but less *energy* as the radio is only transmitting for a brief instant. That is why watching a video over 4G can use less battery than over 3G because even though the 4G radio is less *power efficient*, it spends less time turned on which makes it more *energy efficient*. Now if the transmitter has to compress and encode the data too, then things get a lot more complicated as now some computation has to be done and all bets are off.

Comment: `However, the volume of data in a txt is far less than in a video stream so the txt uses the same power but less energy as the radio is only transmitting for a brief instant`.  

 
I believe power is the rate of energy per unit time, so I do not understand how the power can be same?

Comment: Power is energy divided by unit time not per unit time, one watt os one joule per second, while one joule os one watt multiplied by one second. So 10W for 10s is 100J but 10W for 1mS is only 0.01J, far less energy but the same power

Answer (score 0):

Transmission power depends on the bandwidth and technology of the data link and not on data types. For the same duration, video requires the most bytes to encode, followed by speech and text.

As such, every packet will require the same amount of power; however, depending on what you are transmitting more packets are required for transmission. So yes text requires less power.